# How can i add an Employee in Netsuite using webservices

Tags: netsuite

i am trying to create netsuite employee identity management application in .Net, i have found their CRM Sample application that adds, updates, deletes & search customer, i need to implement function like add employee, delete employee, get all employee, update employee using their web service.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links would help.

http://tellsaqib.github.com/NSPHP-Doc/dc/d5c/class_employee.html

http://tellsaqib.github.com/NSPHP-Doc/da/d81/class_add_request.html